# How do I get Apache to run .php files outside cgi-bin on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, httpd.conf

I'm rewording my previous question for clarity as I don't seem to have had much luck in an answer.

## Issue

I am able to run .php scripts with apache fine as long as I run them in the CGI folder on my server. Could someone please run me through the steps of how to set up the apache-php module to allow .php files to run outside the CGI directory ?

I've seen some methods using built in apache calls such as 'a2enmod' - I have customised my directory structure so I would like to avoid using these built-in functions. That is, I would like to edit the httpd.conf file myself.

This is my first dynamic webpage and any help is appreciated !

Thanks in advance,

Joseph

Comment: That sounds dangerous... if you could, from the web, run a script outside of the "boundaries" (document root) it would open a huge security loophole.

Comment: @HonkderHase The OP talks about changing the way he integrates PHP into his HTTP server. That has nothing to do with what you point out.

Comment: You can check the files installed by that package yourself: `dpkg-query -L libapache2-mod-php`

Comment: Sorry, I am voting to close it as its not about programming.  Its about deploying a website.  Try in Webmasters perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

When I configure my Apache for PHP, I do this:

```
LoadModule php_module        modules/libphp.so

<FilesMatch "\.ph(p?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

[...]

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.phtml
</IfModule>
```

That way, any file named SOMETHING.php or SOMETHING.phtml is automatically handled by the PHP module, regardless where it is inside my DocumentRoot directory structure.

This still restricts the call and execution of php scripts inside the directory (or sub-directory under it) you specified as your DocumentRoot.

The DirectoryIndex defines which file to use if the request does not specify a file.  Ex the request is for https://exemple.com/sample, it will look for index.html, index.php, index.phtml, in that order under the sample directory.